# ANSI C strcmp() function never returning 0, where am I going wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

C isn't the language I know so I'm out of my comfort zone (learning C) and I have ran into an issue that I can't currently figure out.

I am trying to read from a text file one word at a time and compare it to a word that I have passed into the function as a pointer. 
I am currently reading it from the file one character at a time and storing those characters in a new char array until it hits a space, then comparing that char array to the original word stored in the pointer (stored where it's pointing to, anyway).

When I do a printf to check if both arrays are the same they are, they both equal "Hello". At first I thought maybe it's because my char array doesn't have an end terminator but I tried adding one but still nothing is seeming to work.

My code is below and I would appreciate any help. Again C isn't my strong area.

If I do "Hello" it will be > 0 by the way, so I think it's because the gets() stdin function is also including the enter key or something of that sort. I am not sure of a better way to grab the string though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int partA(char*);

main()
{
    // Array to store my string
    char myWord[81];
    // myword = pointer to my char array to store. 80 = the size (maximum). stdin = standard input from my keyboard. 
    fgets(myWord, 80, stdin); 
    partA(myWord);

}

int partA(char *word)
{
    // points to file.  
    FILE *readFile;
    fopen_s(&readFile, "readThisFile.txt", "r");

    char character;
    char newWord[50];
    int i = 0;

    while ((character = fgetc(readFile)) != EOF)
    {
        if (character == ' ')
        {
            newWord[i] = '\0';
            int sameWord = strcmp(word, newWord);
            printf("Word: %s", word);
            printf("newWord: %s", newWord);
            if (sameWord == 0)
                printf(" These words are the same.");
            if (sameWord > 0)
                printf(" sameWord > 0.");
            if (sameWord < 0)
                printf(" sameWord < 0.");
            printf("\n");
            i = 0;
        }
        if (character != ' ')
        {
            newWord[i] = character;
            i++;
        }
        printf("%c", character);


    }

    fclose(readFile);

    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: "so I think it's because the gets() stdin function is also including the enter key". No need to wonder, a reading of the [fgets man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) would tell you that for sure.

Comment: Well, I feel silly. I changed fgets() to gets() and now it's working. So I am curious as to why I shouldn't use gets then. I will take a read through that page, thank you.

Comment: Never use the function `gets()`  it has many problems including letting the user overrun the input buffer.  It has been depreciated for years and completely removed since C11.

Comment: note: function: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: Any modern C compiler will warn you about the function: `getc()` and if using a C standard C11 or later, will not compile your program

Comment: You're conclusion is probably correct. From the [fgets manual page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/): "The newline, if any, is retained.". Thus there is indeed an extra newline at the end of the string. The same manual has also information on `gets`: "The gets() function is equivalent to fgets() with an infinite size and a stream of
stdin, except that the newline character (if any) is not stored in the string.".

Comment: there are other `white space` characters than just 'space' For instance tab, newline, line feed, form feed, back tab, comma, semicolon, colon, question mark, exclamation mark, period, etc etc.  Suggest calling `isalpha()` and/or similar functionality from the header file `ctype.h` for testing the char read

Comment: note: the function: `fgets()` will stop inputting characters at one less than the length given for the buffer, then append a NUL byte to finish filling the buffer so making the buffer 81 bytes and then only reading 80 is unnecessary.

Comment: when calling any of the `fopen()` family of functions, including `fopen_s()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when making a comparison similar to `if (character == ' ')`, always place the literal on the left, so a keypunch error like this: `if (" " = character)` will be caught by the compiler rather than you spending hours and hours of debug time (and growing gray hair) trying to find that missing key stroke.

Comment: @user3629249: you mention `getc()` and say C11 or later won't compile your program.  What are you thinking of?  The `gets()` function was removed from C11, though code that declares it can still use it if it is in the library (and it usually is, for reasons of backwards compatibility).  The `getc()` function is still fully supported; there is no reason not to use it.